# Browserifying a file that contains a node module which doesn't have a .js class in it

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, npm-install

I am trying to browserify my module. I have a dependency on this https://www.npmjs.com/package/chilkat_win32 It is there in my node_modules folder and this is how the structure of it looks.

[image]

As you can see, there is no js class. But there is a .node file. When I run browserify on my module I get the following error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�' (2:2) while parsing G:\Projects\Kube 2.0\edge-node-sdk-typescript\edge-node-sdk-js\node_modules\chilkat_win32\chilkat.node while parsing file: G:\Projects\Kube 2.0\edge-node-sdk-typescript\edge-node-sdk-js\node_modules\chilkat_win32\chilkat.node
    at DestroyableTransform.end [as _flush] (C:\Users\macilamanym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\insert-module-globals\index.js:96:21)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (C:\Users\macilamanym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:115:49)
    at DestroyableTransform.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at prefinish (C:\Users\macilamanym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:465:12)
    at finishMaybe (C:\Users\macilamanym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:473:7)
    at endWritable (C:\Users\macilamanym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:485:3)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (C:\Users\macilamanym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:455:41)
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (C:\Users\macilamanym\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:495:10)
```

Is this because the .node file cannot be read or browserified? If so, how can I cope up with this module and browserify my module? Please advice.

Below is the gulp browserify task.

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    // Single entry point to browserify
    gulp.src('lib/main/EdgeNodeBrowserify.js')
        .pipe(browserify({
          standalone: 'EdgeNode'
        }))
    .pipe(rename('browserEdgeNode.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'))
});
```

Comment: Have you opened up the file and looked in it? Is it just JavaScript in there?

Comment: When I open it contains unknown symbols. Not in a readable format. Tried opening it in notepad++

Comment: @kinakuta I can exclude this module since it contains logic to be executed from server side. But it still says it cannot find the module as the require statements and code pieces are there in the browserify file. Any solutions you can think of?

Comment: When you require in a file (I'm just assuming this is what you mean by dependency), you can put the .js extension, or Node will assume it, but it's not going to assume a .node extension, and even if it did, this file has been compiled, and it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: can  I ignore that peice of code when code is being browserified? Is there such a facility?

Comment: I'm not really clear on how it's included in any list of files to be browserified. Are you using a task runner like Grunt or Guip to do the browserify task?

Comment: yes i'm using gulp

Comment: How is it being included then?

Comment: Edited the question with the gulp task.

Comment: Try adding the ignore property to the object you pass to browserify (takes an array of filename strings) to see if you can exclude it this way. The problem is unexpected, so you'll probably have to experiment.

Comment: I did try ignore. So it ignores it when creating the browserified file. But the code is still there in the browserified file. Therefore when running the code it throws errors saying it can't find that module. Thanks for the help anway :)

Answer (score 3):

It's actually an addon which usually used to provide interface between JavaScript *running in nodejs* and underlying C/C++ libraries. The file is a binary file produced by a build step. In node.js those addons can be included with `require` though they cannot be browserified since it makes no sense.

I'm not sure why do you need such C/C++ bindings in browser side. One way is to ignore such module when bundle

```
    // assuming you use gulp-browserify
    // please be advised not to use that since it's no longer being maintained
    .pipe(browserify({
      ignore : ['chilkat_win32']
    }))
```

Comment: How will this work when I use it with meteorjs? Currently it throws an exception saying its not a valid win 32 application